# Unix 'find' command to include/exclude subdirectories

Tags: unix, find

Say the folder structure looks like this:

```
.
|--folder1
   |--subfolder1
      |--subfolder2
   |--subfolder2
|--folder2
   |--subfolder1
      |--subfolder2
   |--subfolder2
|--folder3
   |--subfolder1
   |--subfolder2
```

I would like to find all files in `subfolder2` only. I know I can just do this:

```
$ find . -type f |grep subfolder2
```

But was wondering if `find` comes with a option to include/exclude given directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just name *all* the directories you want to search.

```
find */subfolder2 -type f
```

Or for a completely arbitrary directory structure, something like this...

```
find $(find . -name subfolder2 -type d) -type f
```

Comment: I edited the original folder structure. Your command only work for same subfolder depth. Is there any way to search **subfolder2** no matter which hierarchy it's?

Comment: @stan Yes, see my edit.

Comment: Your 2nd command got an illegal variable name. This one `find \`find . -name subfolder2 -type d\` -type f` works for me. thanks.

Comment: @Stan You probably aren't using a modern shell like bash, then. The old-style backticks should be fine.

Comment: I am using tcsh in CentOS 5.7. Is that not a modern shell?

Comment: @Stan Ahh...it's not a Bourne shell!